# I'd like to make a wide dialog window in material-ui in React but fullwidth argument does not work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I put the fullscreen parametere in Dialog comoponebt but following code doesn work.
Please give me an adivce... Thank you~~

```
  const theme = useTheme();

  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xl"));
  return (
    <Dialog fullWidth={fullScreen} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
//Omit
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by myself

```
<Dialog maxWidth={"xl"} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fullScreen` property of the [Dialog API](https://material-ui.com/es/api/dialog/):

This should do:

```js
<Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I would like to put the wide width dialo not a full screen one.